# Positioning of css elements not where I am expecting them to be

Tags: html, css, position

http://jsfiddle.net/PerryCS/zFewp/2/

Hi there, I have played around with this for ~6 hours now and I'm getting grumpy because I can't see why it's not working.  :)

If I made the adminHeader small it fits at the top and seems to work properly.  But when I make it bigger the content goes all screwy...

The structure is like this..

adminMaster (the main template where everything goes)
adminHeader (my top portion of the website, inside master)
adminContent (middle, inside master, under header)
adminFooter (bottom, inside master, under content)

My adminContent is in the middle of my header and the footer is right under the content.

I have all 4 "structures" set to relative.  Of course I won't be leaving Administration THAT big when it's done but I need to know WHY the other elements are not going nicely under the header.

They are block elements, nothing is absolute, so they should technically all flow nicely.  On the "common" areas of the website (not posted in this example) I have widths set to pixels (988px), but for the admin portion of the website I would like master to fill the browser window (width:100%) and the other structures (header, content, footer) to fill up the master.

What I need help with... (please)

Why does the layout not flow one after the other?

If its easy (I havnt looked it up yet) - a minimal width (800px) on the Master DIV would be nice.

Comments?  Am I doing this in a bad way?

In case someone missed it - the jsfiddle is at the top :)

Comment: Please post the relevant mark-up, the CSS you've got (in your question), and an image showing what it is you want to end up with. Descriptions lack clarity.

Comment: I had a jsFiddle link right at the very top of the question...  guess you missed it...

Comment: No, I saw the link, I was asking you to bring the code in-line with your question so Stack Overflow isn't dependent on external sites. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of adminHeader is set to 24px. The text is overflowing from the container, which is why you can see it, but the dimensions of the adminHeader are still set to 24px in height. If you increase the height of adminHeader, the following divs will move down the page.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MsjFC/)

Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Wow...  i didnt even think of that!    Thank you so much!  LOL.  I'll add that to my knowledge bank so it never happens again! :)  Much appreciated!   That was the problem.  :)  I wasn't even thinking that was possible that it could overflow the container.  Wowzers...  super easy fix!  Thank you!

Comment: I also forgot that .. I normally never specify the height of a container... I copied and pasted that code from the "common" area and forgot about that height!  On the normal "common" area of the website I use a background image and thus I specified the height!  I'm so happy!   Thanks again!!! :)